# Regex Criteria - Match on either 2 dots, 1 dot at the beginning, or both

Tags: regex

I'm looking to create a REGEX that causes a match on the following criteria

- Two dots next to each other "t..est"
- A dot at the beginning of a phrase ".test"
- Or both "..test"

My knowledge is quite limited on this!

I've tried to set up my own and can get a match on either, but not both?

```
 /(^[.])|(\b([.][.])) /gm
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

The expected outcome is

```
phrase = pass

.phrase = fail

ph..rase = fail

..phrase = fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex, which will fail the match if the very first character is a literal dot or two literal dots are present anywhere in the text,

```
^(?!.*\.\.|\.).*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/elLjzV/1)**